# Pandas Median on index not values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, median

My datas :

```
LogRatio    Strength
 0.555         9.1
 0.542         9.6
 0.533         9.7
 0.532         9.3
 0.519         9.2
 0.508         9.5
```

I want to have the point(LogRatio,Strength) that is the median **position** of my group indexA-indexB

```
indexA = 0
indexB = 4
point_logRatio = df['LogRatio'][indexA:indexB].median()
point_Strength = df[df['LogRatio']==point_logRatio['Strength'].iloc[0]
```

But **I don't want to calcul the median with values**, I just want the index of the row to get the LogRatio and the strength corresponding. Because *point_logRatio* calcul the median and don't give me just the row.
That's why my *point_Strength* doesn't work because the median calculated don't match with a value of the dataframe.

So, if you have an easier way to get the LogRatio and the Strength at the same time where LogRatio is at a **median position** in my dataframe between indexA and indexB, thank you.

At the end, I would like to have :
**point = (0.533 , 9.7)**

Because 0.533 is the logRatio at the median position between my index 0 and 4 in my dataframe and the strength corresponding is 9.7.

Comment: Do you mean `df.iloc[int((0+4)/2),:]]`?

Comment: Yes it's the good results, I thought it was the median but I can use this also, but it will not work if it's not pair. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
median_position = (indexA+indexB)/2
point_logRatio  = df.iloc[median_position]['LogRatio']
point_Strength  = df.iloc[median_position]['Strength']
```